# Finding sample mean of a probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am pretty lost on how to even look at this

Let $X$ be identical and independently distributed exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda = 1$ for $i = 1,2,\dots,n$. Then$\sum X_i \ \sim Gamma (n,1)$. Find the probability that the sample mean is within $2$ standard deviations of the true mean, 
for

- n=4
- n=12
- n=20
- n=20 using an appropriate approximate distribution

I've thought of this so far, which may be wrong:
$$
E(\bar{x}) = 1 \ (which\ I\ figured\ out\ because\ beta=1\ in\ Exp(1)\ )\\
Var(\bar{x}) = \frac{\beta^2}{n} ---> s.d. = \frac{1}{2}
$$
And then I would approximate the probabilities with a normal distribution with a $z$-test. I am basically unsure if I am even going through this correctly though, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must understand the difference between the sample mean and the true mean.  The former is a statistic, therefore a random variable.  The latter is a parameter, thus fixed, and in this case, known.

As you were told, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n, 1)$, where each $X_i \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda = 1)$ is iid.  What this statement indicates is that the **sample total** of $n$ iid observations $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ from an exponential distribution with rate $1$ is gamma distributed with shape $n$ and rate $1$.  Therefore, consider the sample mean $$\bar X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$ which by virtue of a scale transformation, must also be gamma distributed.  Explicitly, and for ease of notation, let $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, so that $\bar X = T_n/n$.  Then $$f_{\bar X}(x) = f_{T_n}(nx) \left|\frac{d}{dx}[nx]\right| = nf_{T_n}(nx) = n \frac{(nx)^{n-1} e^{-nx}}{\Gamma(n)};$$ in other words, $$\bar X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n, n),$$ where the parametrization is by **rate**.  For a general gamma distribution with shape $n$ and rate $\lambda$, the mean is $n/\lambda$ and the variance is $n/\lambda^2$; so $$\operatorname{E}[\bar X] = 1, \quad \operatorname{Var}[\bar X] = 1/n.$$  You would therefore need to numerically calculate for the first case $n = 4$ $$\Pr[1 - 2\sqrt{1/4} < \bar X < 1 + 2\sqrt{1/4}] = \Pr[0 < \bar X < 2]$$ where $\bar X$ is distributed as above.  This can be done, for example, by computing via integration by parts $$\Pr[0 < \bar X < 2] = \int_{x=0}^2 \frac{128}{3} x^3 e^{-4x} \, dx.$$  For $n = 12$, this becomes $$\Pr\left[1 - \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} < X < 1 + \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right] = \frac{2^{16} 3^8}{1925} \int_{x=1-1/\sqrt{3}}^{1+1/\sqrt{3}} x^{11} e^{-12x} \, dx.$$  For $n = 20$, a normal approximation is appropriate; we would say that $$Z = \frac{\bar X - \operatorname{E}[\bar X]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\bar X]}} = \frac{\bar X - 1}{\sqrt{1/20}} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$$ approximately, hence the probability that $\bar X$ is two standard deviations within the mean is simply $$\Pr[|Z| < 2],$$ which we can calculate without any information about $\bar X$--it comes from a standard normal table.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense!!!  Thanks for answering like every part too, I did not expect that

Comment: Oh but one question regarding Γ(n). Is that just the integral from 0 to infinity of x^(n-1)*e^(-n)dx?   
or is it something else?

Comment: @ajdawg For positive integers $n$, $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$, so for example, $\Gamma(4) = 3! = 6$.  The integral representation is not necessary because $n$ is a sample size, and the other parts of the calculation do not apply since you are integrating over a finite interval.